# How do I re-enable SBT Tool Window?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

My SBT Tool Window has disappeared and View -> Tool Windows -> SBT is grayed out.

How can I re-enable/re-show the SBT Tool Window?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your SBT Tool Window goes away and View -> Tool Windows -> SBT is disabled (grayed out) then restart Intellij.